# Order of $GL(n, \mathbb Z_p)$

Tags: group-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be the group of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries of the matrices from the field $\mathbb Z_p$ , $p$ prime, such that determinant of every matrix is not $[0]$ , w.r.t. matrix multiplication ; then what is the order of $G$ ?

Comment: Ok, how many *ordered* basis are there for $\;\left(\Bbb Z_p\right)^n\;$ over $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of bases of an n-dimensional vector space over q-element field.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362312/number-of-bases-of-an-n-dimensional-vector-space-over-q-element-field) and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859520

Answer (score 3):

Further hint:

For any matrix in $\;G\;$ , we look at its columns. The first one cannot be zero, so there are $\;p^n-1\;$ possible choices for it.

Now, the second column **must** be linearly *independent* of the first one, so we must avoid all its $\;p\;$ scalar multiples (pay attention to the fact that this **already** takes care of a possible zeros column), so there are $\;p^n-p=p\left(p^{n-1}-1\right)\;$ possible choices for this second column.

Continue on...

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to count $\text{SL}_n\left(\mathbb{Z}_p\right)$ and consider its cosets with non-zero determinant.

Comment: Not really. $\phantom{--}$